# Validate against only a part of the defined constraints

Tags: validation, symfony, entity

I have this field:

```php
$builder->add('offices', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'ControlPanelBundle:Offices',
    'property' => 'name',
));
```

In my form I am only using one field from all possible fields in this `Offices` object. When I am submitting, it tries to validate all the fields. How can I temporary disable validation only for this time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Validation Groups](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/validation.html#validation-groups) are designed specifically for that.